# How to compare two list value and append that value to new list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
list1 = [{'name': 'Tyler', 'age': '12', 'city': 'SF'}, {'name': 'Caitlyn', 'age': '10', 'city': 'SJ'}]
list2 = [{'age': '12', 'hobby': 'soccer', 'song': 'Abba'}, {'age': '10', 'hobby': 'baseball', 'song': 'Punk'}]
```

Here are the two lists and I want to compare the `age` in each list that matches and append it to list1. Can you guys help me with this?

The results should be

```
list1 = [{'name': 'Tyler', 'age': '12', 'city': 'SF', 'age': '12', 'hobby': 'soccer', 'song': 'Abba'}, {'name': 'Caitlyn', 'age': '10', 'city': 'SJ', 'age': '10', 'hobby': 'baseball', 'song': 'Punk'}]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why didn't you append age 12 to anything?

Comment: @coldspeed I think that's a classic case of why programming is better than manual entry. I think just human error!

Comment: @coldspeed OP did; they appended it into the dictionary with duplicate keys...

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds after I pointed it out.

Comment: @coldspeed - fixed

Comment: @coldspeed dang ninja edits

Comment: Did you mean to merge the dicts with matching ages?

Comment: `[{**d1, **d2} for d1, d2 in zip(list1, list2) if d1['age'] == d2['age']]` if you only want to compare the entries that are at the same positions.

Comment: @bla - yeh, merge i mean

Comment: In that case you can use the solution proposed by @AlexanderReynolds

Comment: If the dictionaries may be out of order in the lists, then you can instead do `[{**d1, **d2} for d1 in list1 for d2 in list2 if d1['age'] == d2['age']]`

Comment: @Alexander Reynolds  - Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to join each dictionary in `list2` into the dictionary  in `list1` with the same value in the `age` key.

Try something like this

```
def join_by_age(list1, list2):
    for item1 in list1:
        for item2 in list2:
            if item1['age'] == item2['age']:
                item1.update(item2)
                break
    return list1

# Join the two lists.
print(join_by_age(list1, list2))
```

Keep in mind that the dictionaries in `list1` will be modified and that if multiple dictionaries in `list2` have the same `age`, only the first will ever be used.

Comment: Would be good to mention that `update()` actually modifies the dictionary inside the list, so it will mutate the input.

Answer (score 0):

**Python 2** An operation as follows

```
for d in list1:
    for e in list2:
        if d['age'] == e['age']:
            d.update(e)
```

**Python 3** You can write in one line as

```
[{**d, **e} if d['age'] == e['age'] else d for d in list1 for e in list2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate lists of dictionaries, but for practical purposes this isn't the most efficient or adaptable structure for what you're looking to do.

If you are happy to use a 3rd party library, you can use Pandas and [`pd.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
import pandas as pd

res = pd.DataFrame(list1).merge(pd.DataFrame(list2))
```

You can then output either a dataframe or a list of dictionaries:

```
print(res)

  age city     name     hobby  song
0  12   SF    Tyler    soccer  Abba
1  10   SJ  Caitlyn  baseball  Punk

print(res.to_dict('records'))

[{'age': '12', 'city': 'SF', 'name': 'Tyler', 'hobby': 'soccer', 'song': 'Abba'}, 
 {'age': '10', 'city': 'SJ', 'name': 'Caitlyn', 'hobby': 'baseball', 'song': 'Punk'}]
```